# Windows Phone 7 Loading Widget?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm building a wp7 app in Silverlight. Is there some system widget/icon/animation/spinner/etc for when something is loading? Or should I implement my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [the PerformanceProgressBar](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/08/performanceprogressbar/)?  Make sure you [also read Part 2](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/08/progressbarperftips2/).